# Angular 10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property (var) of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm just now learning Angular 10 after a long time in AngularJS.  I have a working version of this code which does not set the sorted variable, but I'm using this code to learn why I cannot set the variable sorted within my sortById function.  The code below produces an error at line 29: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sorted' of undefined.

Obviously I do not understand the this. concept within the Angular framework.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { APPLICATIONS } from '../mock-applications';


 @Component({
   selector: 'app-applications',
   templateUrl: './applications.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./applications.component.scss'],
 })

 export class ApplicationsComponent {

     data = APPLICATIONS;  
     sorted:number = 0;

     constructor() {};

     ngOnInit() {};

     // this function is triggered onClick 
     sortById(){
         // not sorted yet
         if(this.sorted === 0 || this.sorted === 2 ){
             this.data.sort(function (a, b) {
                  this.sorted = 1; // ERRROR HERE
                  console.log('asc');
                  return a.Id - b.Id;
             });
         // sorted 
         } else {
               this.data.sort(function (a, b) {
                    this.sorted = 2;
                    console.log('desc');
                    return b.Id - a.Id;
               });
         }
    
         console.log('sorted ' + this.sorted);
     }
```

}

Comment: 'this' does not refer to what you think it does. You need to bind it if you want it to reference the ApplicationsComponent instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
         // not sorted yet
         if(this.sorted === 0 || this.sorted === 2 ){
             this.data.sort(function (a, b) { <--------- loss of scope
                  this.sorted = 1; // ERRROR HERE
                  console.log('asc');
                  return a.Id - b.Id;
             });
         // sorted 
         }
```

Declaring the function this way loses the enclosing scope, in this case `this` probably point to the function instance (tho it could be the window. fun!). If you use an arrow function you will bring in / be bound to the enclosing scope of the component.

```
 if(this.sorted === 0 || this.sorted === 2 ){
             this.data.sort((a, b) => { <--------- arrow function
                  this.sorted = 1; // ERRROR HERE
                  console.log('asc');
                  return a.Id - b.Id;
             });
         // sorted 
         }
```

Here is a nice primer for understanding scope better https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope-e991a8288bc

Comment: Thank you @BrooklynDadCore.  I changed both of those to arrow functions and it worked properly.  I've done a lot of arrow functions in React, but haven't worked in react for awhile and I'm obviously rusty!